# Почему происходит переполнение при 2^31 xor 0

Tags: javascript, битовые-операции

Здравствуйте,не понимаю,почему `alert( Math.pow(2, 31) ^ 0 );` 
дает результат -2147483648.

Почему происходит переполнение?

p.s. 1000...^0000...=1000...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в js побитовые операторы работают с [32битным числами со знаком](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators).

Число 2^31 выходит за ограничения 32битной записи со знаком.

```
2 ^ 31   = 10000000000000000000000000000000 = -2147483648 
           | - это знак
2^31 - 1 = 01111111111111111111111111111111 =  2147483647
```

```js
console.log( (2 ** 31).toString(2).length); // 32 порядка. первый бит - знак.
console.log( (2 ** 31 - 1) ^ 0); // 31 единица, всё еще нормально
```

Comment: Получается запись у  2147483647 и -2147483648 одинаковая?

Comment: @Александр нет. 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) максимальное положительное 32 битное число, записи 2147483648 не существует